# How to add image slider with parallax effect above UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

How to add image slider with parallax effect above UITableView?

https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library - https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader

It is really very good library.

It is able to integrate in swift.

**Swift code**

```
let headerView : ParallaxHeaderView = ParallaxHeaderView.parallaxHeaderViewWithImage(UIImage(named: ""), forSize: CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.height, headerHeight)) as! ParallaxHeaderView

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

func  scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let header: ParallaxHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView as! ParallaxHeaderView
    header.layoutHeaderViewForScrollViewOffset(scrollView.contentOffset)

    self.tblHealthData.tableHeaderView = header

}
```